# How can math signs be cast to string for automation?

Tags: c#, automation

While trying to learn and automate Win calculator in Visual Studio on C#, I can cast buttons' values to string but cannot do that with math signs/operands when reading data from a .csv file:

```
this.UIMap.Click(TestContext.DataRow["Left"].ToString());
this.UIMap.Click(TestContext.DataRow["Oper"].ToString()); <<< this should read operands
this.UIMap.Click(TestContext.DataRow["Right"].ToString());
this.UIMap.ClickEquals();
this.UIMap.AssertEqualsExpectedValues.UIItem11TextDisplayText = 
                        TestContext.DataRow["Res"].ToString();`
```

How can these be handled, please?

Comment: Please notice that this is not casting. You are calling the `ToString()` method. Is it throwing an exception or the value is invalid?

Comment: Looks like the value is invalid because the test fails as it can't find the math signs buttons. But the method Click reads digits buttons with no problem.